# User can't see my Build tab. Where is the permission?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have added some other user to my project in Azure DevOps, but they can't see the Build tab, they can see the Release tab though. Where is the option to allow this?

I have looked at this, at least to my understanding, the Contributor should be able to see the Build?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops

What my user see:

[image]

My user is part of the Contributor group, which according to the docs, should have permission to allow them to see the Builds? Anyway, in the Permission tab, I don't see where to allow them to see the Builds:

[image]

Where's the Build tab? How can I let my user see the Builds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your users need at least a basic license.
By default users with stakeholder license (free) can't see build/release pipeline:

[Azure Devops - About access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops).

But there is a preview feature that you can enable to achieve what you need:

[Provide Stakeholders access to edit build and release pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/provide-stakeholder-pipeline-access?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

In the top right Pipelines page you need to click on the three dots, then on "Manage security":

[image]

Check there if they have permission.

Comment: There is no "Manage Security" button, but there is "Security" button. I've checked inside the "Security" option, the View Builds is already allowed, but my user still can't see the builds